# Combine data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array, ecmascript-6

I got this data structure and I am checking to see which properties are true, then I am adding the `key` for all the properties that are true to that object on a new property called `combined`

```js
const data = [
  {
    keyword: 'banana',
    yellow: true,
    sweet: true
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pineapple',
    yellow: true,
    sweet: false
  },
  {
    keyword: 'apple',
    yellow: false,
    sweet: false
  },
]

const combined = [...data].reduce((acc, { keyword, ...rest}) => {
  const res = Object.entries(rest).reduce((total, [key, value]) => {
    if (value === true) total.push(key)
    return total
  }, [])
  acc.push(res)
  return acc
}, []).map(entry => ({ combined: entry.join(' ') }))

const output = data.map((entry, index) => ({
  ...entry,
  ...combined[index]
}))

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

It seems pretty straight forward but somehow this feels a bit convoluted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a short review;

- Your own answer does read better
- `map` is the right approach
- I would go for `filter` instead of `reduce` (you only want 'true' values that are not keyword)
- I probably would have named `total` -> `keys`
- I prefer `<verb><object>` so `combined` -> `addGroups`
- If you dont use a falsy comparison, then you dont need to check for `'keyword'`

```js
const data = [
    {keyword: 'banana', yellow: true, sweet: true},
    {keyword: 'pineapple', yellow: true, sweet: false},
    {keyword: 'apple', yellow: false, sweet: false},
];

function addGroup(o){
  return {
    ...o,
    group: Object.keys(o).filter(key => o[key] === true).join(' ') 
  };
}

function addGroups(list){
  return list.map(o => addGroup(o));
}

console.log(addGroups(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great. Any reason why you would no do something simpler like this: `const addGroups = (arr) => arr.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  group: Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === true).join(' ')
}))`

Answer (score 0):

I have improved it with this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    keyword: 'banana',
    yellow: true,
    sweet: true
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pineapple',
    yellow: true,
    sweet: false
  },
  {
    keyword: 'apple',
    yellow: false,
    sweet: false
  },
]


const combined = [...data].map((entry) => {

  const group = Object.entries(entry).reduce((total, [key, value]) => {
    if (value && key !== 'keyword')  total.push(key)
    return total
  }, []).join(' ')

  return {
    ...entry,
    group
  }
})


console.log(combined)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Is this a better approach?